# Direct way of changing only one dimension of par("mar")

Tags: r

Usualy I have to change only one dimension of `par("mar")`. I do it this way:

```
mar.new <- par("mar")
mar.new[2] <- 6.1
par(mar = mar.new)
```

But this is 3 lines of code and feels too clumsy. Is there a better way to change single dimension of `par("mar")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if you could do

```
par("mar")[2] <- 6.1
```

but that isn't currently valid `R`. I don't think a `magrittr` chain along the lines of

```
par("mar") %>% `[`(2) %>% `[<-`(par("mar"),2)
```

is going to work either, since these functions use positional matching and we are not feeding in the first argument. So what you posted seems to be best.